# How to use of standard Classic Bluetooth Profiles in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, external-accessory

As far as I understood correctly it *should* be possible to connect to non iOS- and non MFi-devices via Classic Bluetooth, as long as the supported Bluetooth-Profiles (as described in https://support.apple.com/HT204387) are used.

However, I have no idea how to use these profiles (especially PAN) and did not find any examples or documentation that are using them.
Related Questions in the Apple Developer Forums are stale and unanswered for many many years...

When my understanding is correct then

- CoreBluetooth.framework is only for BLE
- ExternalAccessory.framework is only for devices with MFi
- MultipeerConnectivity.framework is only for iOS devices
- BluetoothManager.framework is private - so can't be used in a public app (at least the [BeeTee](https://github.com/michaeldorner/BeeTee) example does list the device...)

**Are there any more options? Did I miss something?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is almost correct until iOS 13, which added GATT over BR/EDR ("Classic"). There's also L2CAP since iOS 11.

There is no app access to other Bluetooth profiles. The device supports them, but there is no SDK.